# Including database connection in mysqli_real_escape_string that is contained in a function

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm not massivley clued up on PHP but I'm using a function to insert data from an array into my database using `mysqli`.

The function is as follows: -

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");

function mysql_insert($con, $table, $inserts) {
    $values = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', array_values($inserts));
    $keys = array_keys($inserts);

    return mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');

    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

Here is the array: -

```
mysql_insert($con, 'table_name', array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'Key3' => 'value3'
));
```

I'm getting the error

> Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in XXX

I know from this that `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires two parameters, the first being the `$con` and the second being the string but I'm having difficulty knowing how to format the code in my function to include the database connection too.

Please can anyone help?

Thanks very much in advanced :)

Comment: better solution: stop escaping things at all and use a prepared statement with placeholders. then you don't have to escape, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't use array_map with mysqli_real_escape_string, because you could only pass one argument.
But you could add an method which calls mysqli_real_escape_string - this could be defined inline like so

```
$values = array_map(function($item) use ($con) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $item);
}, array_values($inserts));
```

Keep in mind, you have to use `use`, because $con isn't visible inside the anonym function.

Comment: well you can, you just have to write the function you use in the call back not use `mysqli_real_escape_string` raw

Comment: Hi Philipp, this was the simplest and non-bloated method, and I like to keep things minimal. :) Thanks for your help! Before I mark this as accepted, @Dagon you mentioned not to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` raw, is this method likely to cause issues going forward?

Answer (score 1):

as you  use mysqli_real_escape_string in procedural mode, you need to pass the "link" so you need to create a custom function for the call back

```
function array_map_callback($a)
{
  global $con;

  return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $a);
}
```

then use

```
$values = array_map('array_map_callback', array_values($inserts));
```

Comment: This method also worked, thank you very much! I'll upvote or accept this when I understand which is the best method.